# recursive update trigger is not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have created 2 tables `abc` and `xyz`. Both table are having the same data as shown below.

Table `abc`:

```
+------+-------+--------+
| roll | name  | status |
+------+-------+--------+
| 1    | john  | I      |
| 1    | ken   | I      |
| 1    | abel  | I      |
| 2    | aston | I      |
| 2    | ron   | I      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Table `xyz`:

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| roll1 | name1 | status1 |
+-------+-------+---------+
| 1     | john  | I       |
| 1     | ken   | I       |
| 1     | abel  | I       |
| 2     | aston | I       |
| 2     | ron   | I       |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

The status in both tables can be updated to `'D'` or `'E'`. Suppose in table `abc`, if the status of `John` become `'D'` then I need to take `John's` roll (that is `1`) and update all the status in  `xyz` to `'D'` where `roll1 = 1`.

Similarly, suppose if the status of `ron` changed to `'E'` in `xyz` table, then `aston` and `ron` status should be `'E'` in table `abc`.

This need to be achieved using update triggers. I have created 2 update trigger for both the tables. The trigger used are

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `test2`.`abc_trigg`$$

create trigger `test2`.`abc_trigg` BEFORE UPDATE on `test2`.`abc`   
for each row BEGIN  
  IF @__disable_trigger is null THEN  
    SET @__disable_trigger = 1;  
    if new.status = 'D' then  
      update xyz set status1='D' where roll1 = new.roll;      
    elseif new.status = 'E' then   
      update xyz set status1='E' where roll1 = new.roll;  
    end if;  
  end if;  
end;  
$$  

DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `test2`.`xyz_trigg`$$  
create trigger `test2`.`xyz_trigg` BEFORE UPDATE on `test2`.`xyz`   
for each row BEGIN  
  IF @__disable_trigger is null THEN  
    SET @__disable_trigger = 1;  
    if new.status1 = 'D' then  
      update abc set status='D' where roll = new.roll1;  
    elseif new.status1 = 'E' then  
      update abc set status='E' where roll = new.roll1;  
    end if;  
  end if;  
end;  
$$  

DELIMITER ;
```

But these triggers are not correct and I am not getting the expected output. Kindly guide me to fix the issue and help me to get the relevant output?

Comment: You haven't stated what is not correct and what is wrong, but you seem to have lots of logic code - why not just `update xyz set status1 = new.status where roll1 = new.roll` ? And do it `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: HI, Thank you for you reply. I cannot use update xyz set status1 = new.status where roll1 = new.roll . The reason I am using the if condition is, whenever I updates the status = 'D' then update the corresponding ID's status in second table to 'D';  same for 'E'. For any other alphabets, nothing need to be done. According to the trigger this is not happening. Also when I update the second table its update trigger shoots and result in an infinite loop condition, in order to avoid that , I used the variables initially. But that also doesn't help much.Could you please suggest

Comment: I understand the problem more now. Perhaps try changing both the triggers to `AFTER UPDATE` and adding `and status != 'D'` to each of the updates (change `D` to `E` where required). Also remove the `disable_trigger` since it doesn't help.

Also, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784543/mysql-trigger-loop

Comment: Also, this link may help. Note that the technique with the global variable flag (disable_trigger) needs to be switched on and off either side of the embedded update. http://www.mzcart.com/mysql-how-to-stop-infinite-loop-in-mysql-trigger/